# Cannot get the current directory in .vbs file

Tags: vbscript

I write a Visual Basic Script to execute an Excel Macro. I want to set the location of .xlsm file dynamically. I use FileSystemObject to get the current directory. It returns C:\Windows\System32 but I need the directory where the .vbs file is located.

I tried to get the current directory with FileSystemObject and WScript without success.

```
' Create a FileSystemObject to get the current directory
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strPath

' Open the Workbook specified on the command-line 
Dim oWorkBook
Dim strWorkerWB
strWorkerWB = strPath & "\Data center Wattsight long term.xlsm"

Set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Open(strWorkerWB)
```

The expected behaviour is to open the Excel file. But I get an error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the *current working directory* with the *location* of your script. The two are not identical.

Either of these will give you the *current working directory*:

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
```

```vb
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

This will give you the *location* of the script:

```vb
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```